# How to Print a receipt in C# without manual interaction

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have an application which passes parameters from form1 to form2.
I want form2 layout only to be printed with the information sent from form1.

But I do not want to have any manual interaction on form2 like upon click of
a button sending the form to the printer.

But on a single click on the form1 the data and controls and layout to be visible
on form2 needs to be sent directly to the printer, and I need to have a copy of the
receipt.

could there b any specific ways to do so, I was successful in printing the form after the
data comes from first form1's click then appears on form2...and upon click on form2
form is getting printed.....

But I want the same operation on the form1 itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this.

On your form1 pass the parameters in form2 and then on 
form2 formload event call the method of printing.

Best Regards

Comment: Thankyou it worked ! But i was using visible 'false' and close functions to close the window....which totally doesn't handle the print option invisibly. How can I make it totally invisible upon first form's button click i need to start up print of second page without second form display for atleast a sec.